# Laravel Homestead/Vagrant - Installing programs

Tags: laravel, vagrant

I am using Laravel Homestead as my vagrant box. I am not really familiar with vagrant, however. If I install some things like "Lame" for example, when I suspend the box it is gone and I have to re-install next time I do a vagrant up. I guess this makes sense.

My question is, how can I get the homestead box to keep lame installed after suspending the box?

Comment: It shouldn't be gone on a suspend. If you're doing `vagrant halt`, changes will persist. Are you doing `vagrant destroy`?

Comment: @ceehayoz I am not doing a destroy no. Let me check again.

Comment: @ceejayoz using vagrant halt worked. If you will set your comment as an answer I will accept it as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vagrant destroy` deletes your virtual machine and the next `vagrant up` recreates it from the base image.

Using `vagrant halt` suspends your virtual machine. The next `vagrant up` merely starts it back up again, and any changes/customizations are retained.